# Import SVG option doesn't appear on the import menu

Tags: import, svg

I am using Blender 2.81 and 2.82a.
I want to import a SVG graphics, but the import SVG option doesn't appear on the import menu. I checked on both Blender 2.81 and 2.82a and it doesn't show. I checked on Add-ons, and the only import add-on I see is the AutoCAD DXF. Is this normal?

Does anyone know what can I do to bring the import SVG option back?

Thanks

[image: Import options]

Answer (score 5):

Enable the Import-Export SVG add-on in the user preferences

[image]

Comment: Oh, there it is. Thank you very much, you saved my day. How come I didn't see it before? I only saw the import AutoCAD DXF. 